# In Tensorflow, how do you feed the enqueue op when using QueueRunner?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm confused about the purpose of `QueueRunner` in tensorflow.

In reading the documentation: https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/threading_and_queues

I am writing my own code to load a sample from my custom database and load it to a queue in tensorflow. I've defined a `FIFOQueue` (I handle permuting order) and the appropriate `enqueue` op.

The `Coordinator` makes sense, my code uses it to know when to shut down the enqueueing threads. But the purpose of the `QueueRunner` confuses me.

The `QueueRunner` runs an `enqueue` op repeatedly. But the documentation doesn't talk about how to feed data to that enqueue op.

> Obviously an enqueue operation requires that you feed it with
>   something. So is `QueueRunner` only meant to be used when you're
>   loading from tensorflow records (e.g. all enqueue operations are
>   themselves ops in the graph)?

If the above statement is correct, then I understand (and wish the documentation was as explicit). In that case `QueueRunner` is not for me to use in this case because all enqueue operations are not graph ops. If I'm wrong, please correct me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through this a few times over now I understand the scenario, and my statement in the question is correct. The QueueRunner only runs a TF op in a loop and handles housekeeping. So any loading operations that are performed 100% in the graph, such as reading from a TF datafile, will benefit from QueueRunner, but if you need to load your data from outside of tensorflow you'll need to write your own thread and loop over enqueue operations yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

```
def feed(images, labels, im, label, epochs=None):
    epochs_elapsed = 0
    while epochs is None or epochs_elapsed < epochs:
        for i in range(len(images)):
            yield {im: images[i], label: labels[i]}
        epochs_elapsed += 1


def tf_ops(images, labels, capacity=128):
    im = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=(None,None,3))
    label = tf.placeholder(tf.int32,shape=())
    shapes = [(None,None,3), ()]
    queue = tf.PaddingFIFOQueue(capacity, [tf.float32, tf.int32],shapes=shapes)
    enqueue_op = queue.enqueue([im, label])
    fqr = FeedingQueueRunner(queue, [enqueue_op],
                             feed_fns=[feed(images, labels,im, label).next()])
    tf.train.add_queue_runner(fqr)
    return queue.dequeue()
source_im,source_label = tf_ops(source_images,source_labels)
```